# How to create grouped products in Magento 1.7 using PHP

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to create a grouped products in Magento Community Edition 1.7 using PHP but going around in circles. I can create a simple product following this guide:

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/programatically-manually-creating-simple-magento-product/

But I want to create grouped products instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case someone else is wondering for the full code. Here it is. Hope it helps someone.

```
$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();

if (file_exists($imagePath)) {
    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath,array('thumbnail','small_image','image'),false,false);
}else{
    $fp = fopen('temp/missingImages.txt', 'a');
    fwrite($fp, $sku."\n");
    fclose($fp);
}


$product->setSku($sku.'-grouped');
$product->setAttributeSetId(4);
$product->setTypeId('grouped');
$product->setName($title);
$product->setSubtitle($subtitle);
$product->setCategoryIds($magentoCatId);
$product->setWebsiteIDs(array(1)); 
$product->setDescription($description);
$product->setShortDescription($description);
$product->setPrice($price);
$product->setAuthor($author);
$product->setEditor($editor);
$product->setTable_of_contents($contents);
$product->setFormat($format);               
$product->setWidth($width);
$product->setHeight($height);   
$product->setNumber_of_pages($pagenumber);              
$product->setPublisher($publisher);
$product->setWeight(4.0000);
$product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
$product->setStatus(1);
$product->setTaxClassId(0); # My default tax class
$product->setStockData(array(
    'is_in_stock' => 1,
    'manage_stock' => 0,
    'use_config_manage_stock' => 1
));

try {
    $product->save();
    echo 'Grouped Product ID: '.$product->getId()." - SKU - ".$sku."-grouped<br/>";
    $group_product_id = $product->getId();


    $assocSql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `groupingId` = '".$sku."' ";
    $assocQuery = mysql_query($assocSql);
    while($assocRow = mysql_fetch_array($assocQuery)){                      
        $simple_product_id[] = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getIdBySku( $assocRow['id']);
    }


    $products_links = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_link_api');
    $group_product_id = $product->getId();

    foreach($simple_product_id as $groupedProd){                
        $products_links->assign ("grouped",$group_product_id,$groupedProd); 
    }

}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage(). " First catch SKU is - ".$sku."<br/>";
    $fp = fopen('temp/missingSku.txt', 'a');
    fwrite($fp, $sku."\n");
    fclose($fp);
}

$cache = Mage::getSingleton('core/cache');
$cache->flush();
```

Julian :)

Comment: hi @Julian, above code helped you, you have accepted that answer but after that you have posted your code and unaccepted mine.It's not good thing

Comment: @AnilGupta Your code is still up voted and the reason I took the tick off your answer and pasted it in mine is because your answer is confusing.
You give the correct links but to a novice it does not explain too much.
For that reason it is still up voted just moved the tick to a more appropriate answer.

Comment: So could you please remove the down vote as I think this will help a lot of people out there

Comment: @AnilGupta you should be able to up vote by just clicking on the up button?

Comment: giving this error : You last voted on this answer
1 hour ago
Your vote is now locked in
unless this answer is edited

Answer (score 1):

```
Please see below code to create grouped product as we need to add all product in  gruop data 

    $products_links = Mage::getModel(‘catalog/product_link_api’);
    $products_links->assign (“grouped”,$group_prod_id,$new_prod_id);
```

Please see refference sites for more information :
        http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/programatically-manually-creating-simple-magento-product/ and http://blog.onlinebizsoft.com/magento-programmatically-create-grouped-product-for-import-code/